# KSOAP2 is adding id property to SOAP request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm using this code to consume a SOAP web service from my Android app:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Element headerElements[] = new Element[2];
    headerElements[0] = new Element().createElement(HEADER_NAMESPACE,"locale");
    headerElements[0].addChild(Node.TEXT,"es_MX");
    Element authElement = new Element().createElement(HEADER_NAMESPACE,"authentication");
    Element usernameElement = new Element().createElement(HEADER_NAMESPACE,"username");
    usernameElement.addChild(Node.TEXT,"myUser");
    Element pwdElement = new Element().createElement(HEADER_NAMESPACE,"password");
    pwdElement.addChild(Node.TEXT,"pwd");
    authElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameElement);
    authElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pwdElement);
    authElement.setPrefix(null, HEADER_NAMESPACE);
    headerElements[1] = authElement;
    envelope.headerOut = headerElements;
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("myapp",e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.i("dump request", httpTransport.requestDump);
```

but at the server side i'm getting an error like this:

> Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'n1:listAssignments'

...this is the XML request generated

```
<v:Envelope 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<v:Header>
    <n0:locale xmlns:n0="http://mycompany.com/ws/soapheaders">es_MX</n0:locale>
    <n1:authentication xmlns:n1="http://mycompany.com/ws/soapheaders">
        <n1:username>myUser</n1:username>
        <n1:password>pwd</n1:password>
    </n1:authentication>
</v:Header>
<v:Body>
    <n2:listAssignments id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n2="http://example.com/mx/mycompany/ws/webadjuster/WebAdjusterAPI" />
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the generated XML request contains an "id" and "c:root" atributes. Why is this happening? how can i avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);"
```

Before this :

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true;

envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
```